# zipping / compressing xsl file

Tags: apache, zip, gzip

I have xsl file whose size is approx 12kb, i want to zip it.
Is there any way to zip xsl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/page1">
    <form name="form1" style="margin:0px;padding:0px" action="action.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkData();">
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="op1 />        
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="op2 />
    </form>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Its more of general question
i want to know how to compress/zip xsl files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your server. On Apache, you need to activate mod_gzip in your httpd.conf file. Googling for mod_gzip will provide plenty of guides on enabling it.

If you cannot edit your root Apache configuration, there are two alternatives. If the XML file is static, compress it manually, name the file foo.xsl.gz and if not already active, turn on `MultiViews` in the `.htaccess` file for that directory. If the XML file is not static, or if you cannot even use .htaccess, the last resort is to change the XML file to a PHP script, and wrap your ob_* commands around the code to spit out the XML.

Comment: i am using Apache and using gzip for php compressing, i want to know how to do the same for xsl files

like in php we use "ob_start("ob_gzhandler");"

Comment: yes, mod_gzip is your answer. It will also compress PHP output after PHP has finished executing (so you don't need to use output buffering)

Comment: that i cant change because of dependencies , is any alternate solution is there

Comment: @BrainBuddies I updated my answer. Does it not cover your use case? What more are you looking for?

Comment: i can't convert in a php file

how can i using MultiViews in .htacess file.
my file is www.mywebiste.com/testing/abc.xsl

Comment: just zip it up and put it in the folder next to the original. Apache will select the smaller file (the compressed one) if the client can Accept the MIME type associated with .gz

Comment: In folder www.mywebiste.com/testing/

i put file abc.xsl.gz , but if i am calling abc.xsl only , so its still calling xsl file not the zipped one.

i am using firefox

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19621/discussion-between-brain-buddies-and-nicholas)